# 1:N relationship representation in dbdesigner

Tags: database, database-design

I'm using dbdesigner to create my logical model and i'm confused about a simple 1:N relationship representation.

[image]

USUARIO AND FUNCAO have a N:M relationship...no biggie. But the thing is about the PERFIL and USUARIO relationship. It's a 1:N relationship. The user can only have one profile (PERFIL) and one PROFILE (perfil) can be associated with many users. Shouldn't the cardinality be [1,*] near USUARIO and [1,1] near PERFIL?

I'm using dbdesigner and pretty clueless about database modeling.

Comment: Yes, it should be. But you probably have other questions, like, how did you do that and how to get it the other way? (What exact product are you using?)

Comment: i'm using dbdesigner fork

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have set up your relationships properly. It looks like you have the gui set up to label your links in the opposite direction.

Check Display menu Notation choices. You probably want EER or Traditional to label ends 1 & n. Also check Options menu Model Options.

It looks like you used a 1:n Relation Tool (Non-Identifying Relation) to link from PROFIL to USARIO. This created Rel_05 and USARIO id_profil with "(FK)". This does mean there is a 1:n relationship from profiles to users.

Notice that all your 1:n lines to FKs have the [1,1] at the FK end and the [1,*] is at the far side of the diamond. Yet these are all 1:n the other way.